# Dial-gauge pressure canner process times

Tags: pressure-canner

Dial-gauge pressure canner process times

I am confused about the cooking process times for various ingredients. I have a Presto 01781 23-Quart Dial-gauge Pressure Canner.

According to a website:

- [Raw Mixed Vegetables should be processed at 11 pounds of pressure for 90 minutes](https://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_04/mixed_vegetables.html)
- [Carrots should be processed at 11 pounds of pressure for 30 minutes](https://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_04/carrots_sliced.html)
- [Soups should be processed at 11 pounds of pressure for 75 minutes](https://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_04/soups.html)
- [Pasta sauce with veggies without meat should be processed at 11 pounds of pressure for 25 minutes](https://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_03/spaghetti_sauce.html)

Why does Pasta sauce with veggies take 25 minutes, but mixed vegetables take 90 minutes? Is it because the pasta with veggies are fully cooked? They say you should process for the time of the longest processing ingredient.

How long should I process my fully cooked and strained tomato sauce if is contains mixed vegetables? 25 or 90 minutes? This is how it is prepared. I add crushed and peeled tomatoes from my garden to a large pot. I add chopped green pepper, red pepper, onions, basil oregano, and parsley, salt and black pepper and small chopped carrots. It is then cooked and boiled for 1.5 hours. Then I pour the sauce through a fine strainer and remove the veggies, carrots, herbs. I am left with a smooth sauce. This is added to a quart sized ball mason jar. I add citric acid and lemon juice.

Since this sauce contains all of these cooked veggies and carrots, Although they have been strained out, should I consider processing for the ingredient that takes the longest to process like the mixed vegetables, so 11 pounds of pressure for 90 minutes?

Comment: I assume it may have to do with the fact that tomato is quite acidic, and "mixed vegetables" likely are not. Also notice how the pasta sauce listing says "pasta sauce with veggies" which sounds exactly like what you made.

Comment: Esther: you should post that as an answer.

Comment: The 90min time for mixed vegetables is due to them being raw and cold when they go in.